# Creating a method that can operate on 2 strings

Tags: scala

Say I wanted to create a new operator in scala that would do this:

```
val a = "hello"
val b = "world" | a
```

This new method named `|` would operate on 2 strings, they could also be potentially Options.

If the first string is `None` or `""`, then fall back to the 2nd value `a`.

So:

```
val a = "hello"
val b = "world" | a
b is "world"
```

And:

```
val a = "hello"
val b = "" | a
b is "hello"
```

And

```
val a: Option[String] = None
val b = a | "world"
b is "world"
```

If someone could explain how they can write this and what Scala features allow DSL like this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can define extension methods

```
implicit class StringOptionOps(s: Option[String]) {
  def |(s1: String): String         = orElse(s, Some(s1))
  def |(s1: Option[String]): String = orElse(s, s1)
}

implicit class StringOps(s: String) {
  def |(s1: String): String         = orElse(Some(s), Some(s1))
  def |(s1: Option[String]): String = orElse(Some(s), s1)
}

def orElse(s: Option[String], s1: Option[String]): String =
  s.filter(_.nonEmpty).orElse(s1).getOrElse("")
```